# How to set editText's text property in specified positions on Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There are 5 rows(items) in a `Recyclerview` and it contains `Checkbox`(cbox) and editText(noOfQst). I can set current holder editText's text property using below code in my `onBindviewHolder` class.

```
holder.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

But what I need is to set all the editText's value together such as the below code

```
firstrow.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
secondrow.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
thirdrow.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
fourthrow.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
fifthrow.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

I am doing this because need to set the value when user change the checkbox's state.The following is my piece of code for your understanding.

```
holder.cbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    //set your object's last status
                    tblchapter.setSelected(isChecked);
                    tblchapter.setVisibled(isChecked);


                    //if checkbox checked display EditText(No of qstns), else hide it.
                    if (holder.cbox.isChecked()) {
                            checkedCount+=1;
                            holder.noOfQst.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            holder.noOfQst.requestFocus();

                               if(checkedCount>0)
                                    {
                                        int value = 40/checkedCount;
                                        holder.noOfQst.setText(String.valueOf(value));

                                    }
                                }
                            }

                        }
                     else {
                            checkedCount-=1;
                            holder.noOfQst.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            holder.noOfQst.setText(""); //remove entered value when uncheck

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: recyclerviews normally used in situations where you want to apply same logic to each entry

Comment: When you change or want to change some item in RecyclerView, you should call notifyItemChanged(position) of the RecyclerView adapter

Comment: @pooya...I need to change all my editText's text property dynamically whenever user clicks on checkbox. Situation is like that. Any idea to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get children of `RecyclerView` using, `RecyclerView.getChildAt()` . It will give you all the children which are currently visible in the mobile.

```
for(i = 0; i < recyclerView.getChildCount(); i++)
{
    final View child = recyclerView.getChildAt(i);
    // do something with the View. like setting the text to TextView
}
```

Comment: I am working on adapter class. I can do this way if you could help me to pass an array to base class. Any suggestion for this?

Comment: Sorry. could you explain a bit more? what array? what base class?

Comment: Recyclerview is in my **examfragment.java** class and adapter class is **chapteradapter.java**.  I have an integer array named **childcount[]** in **chapteradapter** class so I need to pass this **childcount[]** to **examfragment** class.

Comment: Are you creating the adapter from the fragment? If yes, you can pass the reference of the fragment to the adapter.  Have a method named setArray in the fragment. Then call that method from the adapter using the fragment reference.

Comment: Sorry Dinesh, I need to pass value from adapter to fragment not fragment to adapter. Is it possible?

Comment: To pass the data from adapter to fragment, you should have a reference of the Fragment at the adapter. So do you have it? Where are you creating the adapter?